# How to find through scripts that peer-to-peer file-sharing applications are installed in Linux?

Tags: package-management, rpm

We want to find out whether there is any peer-to-peer file sharing is installed on Linux machine. Some examples of these applications include -

- Napster
- Kazaa
- ARES
- Limewire
- IRC Chat Relay
- BitTorrent

How do we script it whether above application's RPM are installed or even using find search? Basically I need the search words for above peer-to-peer applications to find them.

### Update

Here are the commands i use to search them. Am i missing any thing?

```
rpm -qa |grep -i bittorrent
rpm -qa |grep -i limewire
rpm -qa |grep -i kazaa
rpm -qa |grep -i ares
rpm -qa |grep -i napster
rpm -qa |grep -i irc
rpm -qa |grep -i irssi
rpm -qa |grep -i xchat

find / -name bittorrent
find / -name limewire
find / -name kazaa
find / -name ares
find / -name napster
find / -name irc
```

Comment: 1. You are probably best by searching with whatever package manager is available, in this case, probably `rpm` or `dnf` (`yum`'s successor). 2. Why? 3. You think IRC is p2p file sharing?

Comment: Those are the application listed in IRS audit lookup.

Comment: That is hilarious and yet unsurprising. IRC is not a p2p file sharing service (by any sensible definition). As for searching, most sensible package managers will provide search utilities to query installed packages (and if it doesn't have a built-in option to search package descriptions, you should be able to just use `grep` to filter for search terms that interest you (e.g., "file sharing")).

Comment: @HalosGhost I found [this](http://www.irs.gov/irm/part10/irm_10-008-027.html) which doesn't mention IRC under Exhibit 10.8.27-1  section F. I suppose you could transfer a program through IRC, but I wouldn't accept anything through IRC even if my life depended on it.

Comment: @SailorCire, nor is that really what IRC is intended for (nor would it be very good at such transfers).

Comment: @HalosGhost agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the name of the programs/packages each on its own line in a file, say `packages.txt`, and use `rpm -qa |grep -iFf packages.txt`

Now ... the second part, with the `find` command seems rather silly. This is somewhat Linux-specific: Better to run (as root) `ps` and/or `netstat -nap` for any daemons and processes listening to ports. Some of these are `udp` only, so they won't be in the `LISTEN` state.

```
netstat -tap |grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)" | grep -iFf packages.txt
netstat -uap |grep -iFf packages.txt
ps -axo pid,user,args | grep -iFf packages.txt
```

You can sort of condense all the above into:

```
{ 
  rpm -qa
  netstat -tap |grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)" 
  netstat -uap 
  ps -axo pid,user,args
} | grep -iFf packages.txt
```

But then you'd have to figure out which output grep matched.